# Reversible translation table in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I need a function that can make a translation that can also be reversed, in this case to convert to and from subscript.

As far as I know, the maketrans() method only works in one direction - so that doesn't work for this application.

My working but inelegant solution:

```
def subScript(x, y):
    if y == True: return str(x).translate(str.maketrans('₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉', '0123456789'))
    return str(x).translate(str.maketrans('0123456789', '₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉'))
```

Which returns `"0123456789"` for `subScript("₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉", True)`
and `"₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉"` for `subScript("0123456789", True)`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What prevents you from merging the 2 translation tables (`maketrans('₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉0123456789', '0123456789₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉')`)? That way no need for the flag!

Comment: If `subScript()` is called frequently, it might be worth defining the translation table once and reusing it.

Comment: @Swifty but this changes the function behaviour. It is not "invert_position" (your suggestion) as currently written, but "convert all to/from subscript".

Comment: @SUTerliakov: indeed if the input text contains mixed numbers it will do what you say, but the context is actually not very clear about that. Well, either it solves the "problem", either it doesn't :) Another possibility would be to create a dictionary `{'to': ('0123456789', '₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉'), 'from': ('₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉', '0123456789')}` and use the relevant value in maketrans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, I added my own layer of laziness to Alain T.'s nice answer and got this:

```
subMap   = ['0123456789','₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉']

def subScript(x, y):
    return str(x).translate(str.maketrans(*subMap[::y]))

subScript('Golgoth7', 1)
Out[55]: 'Golgoth₇'

subScript('Ulysse₃₁', -1)
Out[56]: 'Ulysse31'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define two translation tables and pick the one you need based on the parameter:

```
subMap   = ['0123456789','₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉']
subTrans = [str.maketrans(*subMap), str.maketrans(*reversed(subMap))]

def subScript(x, y):
    return str(x).translate(subTrans[y])
```